# Content Editable inside a block anchor selection issue

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfYMF/3/

```
.inner{
  width:500px; 
  background-color:#555; 
  text-align:center; 
  display:table-cell;    
}
.outer{
    display:block;
}
...
<a href="#button" class="outer">
    <span>
        <span class="inner" contenteditable=true>FooBar</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I have a content editable span inside an anchor with the text center aligned. The anchor is set to display block. Under these conditions dragging from the left or right drags the element instead of selecting the text. Removing the display:block or changing the element to a div allows it to work fine.

Is there any way to make selecting text starting on the far sides of the aligned text work with the block anchor?

This is in chrome. The other browsers appear to do similarly, but like to drop and copy the dragged content back into the content-editable causing markup cannibalism.

Comment: Can you please explain why the block is so important? Is there some functionality you are trying to preserve by using it? Or is it a styling thing? Or?

Comment: Functional and styling. In actual application the outer anchor has a height [and a link] set on it as a large "button". It would be ideal to preserve the anchor so the link works without javascript, and yet can still have a height so the entire button is clickable.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did any one figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bug in browsers, check this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738749)

In the meantime you can fix this by preventing default action on dragstart event on the troubled anchor tag.

```
a.ondragstart = function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); }
```